# unable to print the list of maps in html for below code in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I am unable to print the value in HTML for below code in angular js, can any one help on this?

angularjs controller code :

```
$scope.arr=[new Map().set("MYKEY","MYVALUE")];
```

html code :

```
{{arr}}
```

Can any one tell how to display this using angular js tags in html.

Comment: $scope.arr=[new Map().set("MYKEY","MYVALUE")];

Answer (score 0):

You should use $scope.arr to access data from DOM.

Angularjs controller code :

> $scope.arr = [new Map().set("MYKEY","MYVALUE")];

Html code:

> {{arr}}

Comment: sorry i used same. but no result on html. showing {}

Answer (score 0):

I have tried below code its working, please check it once.

Angularjs code:

> $scope.DATA = []; 
>      var arr =[new Map().set("MYKEY","MYVALUE")]; 
>      angular.forEach(arr, function (iterate) {
>      angular.forEach(iterate, function (value, key) {
>     $scope.DATA.push( { key :  key, value : value } );
>     })
>   });

Html code:
      `<ul>
         <li ng-repeat='(key, value) in DATA'>
           <span>Key: {{value.key}}</span>
           <span>value: {{value.value}}</span> 
        </li>
      </ul>`

Answer (score 0):

Its done by---> [Amruth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6781889/amruth)

Thank You Amruth...!!! It was really helpfull........!!!!